# Add var from .kt in activity main

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, qr-code

i had a QR Scanner from the internet. But my Kotin skills are not available...

How can I add a COUNTER, that count my times, I scaned a code?
[code of counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHRGZ.png)

Now I want to see that counter in the activity main. But how can I put a Text to that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgSG4.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Leave hint blank you don't need to add hint.**
And delete the line where you wrote the log and replace it with the following code;

```
HGCounter.setText(COUNTER.toString());
```